# Activate Chrome Extension Background Page Via Message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write my very first chrome extension, and working on getting message passing and background.js working. It looks like my background.js is never getting called or receiving any messages. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here's a minimal example:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "RAData",
  "version": "0.1",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [
      "<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"] }]
}
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("message from content");
console.log("content.js loaded");
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log("message received");
});
console.log("background.js loaded");
```

What I think should happen is whenever I load a page, content.js should load, print "content.js loaded" to the console, then wake background.js with the message.  Background.js should then print "message received" and "background.js loaded" to the console.

Instead, the console just shows "content.js loaded" - it doesn't look like any of the code in background.js is ever executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looking at the console for the background page. You can access it by clicking "background page" next to "Inspect views:" for your extension at chrome://extensions

Comment: oooh.  I didn't realize they had different consoles.  well, that was simple. :-)